# Why have I click twice on a marker on FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, firefox

I am working on something involving google maps and markers. I have a script which does a lot of things at a web-page. The script opens a popup when a user clicks on a marker, however, under FireFox I have to click twice on the marker to trigger the event. I have the impression that for some reason it does not know that the marker event should be triggered. Relevant part:

```
function openMarker() {
    //Some code here
}

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: lat, lng: lon},
        zoom: 14
    };

    //...

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    function createMarker(la, lo, title, description, officialName, realName, id) {
        markers[markers.length] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(la,lo),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: title,
            description: description,
            officialName: officialName,
            realName: realName,
            id: id
        });

        //...
    }
//...
}
```

You can view more details [here](http://szkoz.com/js/ui/hungarian-map/hungarian-map-common.js). This is the [page](http://szkoz.com/hungarian-map/city/borberek). Thanks.

Comment: Works as expected for me on FF

Comment: @A.Wolff, is it opening a popup for you on FireFox? That's pretty strange, since the behavior is different on my end. It behaves just like I described in the question. Very strange. My instance is 39.0 on Windows 8.

Comment: load the release-version of the API: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyBAojWfHrfUBQvxASa56JUf3dBEXRzCBww

Comment: @Dr.Molle, that solves the problem. Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it?